# PySpark DataFrame: find array column's index that's closest to integer column's value

Tags: python, arrays, pyspark

I have a PySpark DataFrame that has an array column type and an integer column type. I want to figure out which array position that integer column is closest to in terms of value. See below:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[
    (1, [5, 20, 100, 250], 2),  
    (2, [16, 53, 120, 180], 168),
    (3, [100, 200, 1000, 2500], 3500),
],
["id", "array_col", "int_col"]  
)
```

I want to create a new column that sees which array index in array_col that the int_col's value is closest to, producing a new df like this:

```
| ID      | array_col              | int_col | closest_index |
| 1       | [5, 20, 100, 250]      | 2       | 0             |
| 2       | [16, 53, 120, 180]     | 168     | 3             |
| 3       | [100, 200, 1000, 2500] | 3501    | 3             |
```

I've tried doing something like this:

```
def find_nearest(value):
    res = bin_array[np.newaxis, :] - value.values[:, np.newaxis]
    ret_vals = [bin_array[np.argmin(np.abs(i))] for i in res]
    return pd.Series(ret_vals)
```

And then from there, using the array_position function to locate the index location, but no luck on a DataFrame. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a UDF that finds the nearest index and then use it for each row.

Here's an example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


def find_nearest_index(array, value):
    return min(range(len(array)), key=lambda i: abs(array[i] - value))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("Test").getOrCreate()
    df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [
            (1, [5, 20, 100, 250], 2),
            (2, [16, 53, 120, 180], 168),
            (3, [100, 200, 1000, 2500], 3500),
        ],
        ["id", "array_col", "int_col"],
    )
    nearest_index_udf = F.udf(lambda x, y: find_nearest_index(x, y))
    df = df.withColumn(
        "Nearest Index", nearest_index_udf(F.col("array_col"), F.col("int_col"))
    )
```

Gives result:

```
+---+--------------------+-------+-------------+
| id|           array_col|int_col|Nearest Index|
+---+--------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1|   [5, 20, 100, 250]|      2|            0|
|  2|  [16, 53, 120, 180]|    168|            3|
|  3|[100, 200, 1000, ...|   3500|            3|
+---+--------------------+-------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use posexplode() function to explode the array which also adds the position column, and then identify the closest values and retrieve the relevant rows as in the code below:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# explode original df and add "delta" column with distance of position from "int_col" 
df1 = (df
   .select("*", F.posexplode("array_col"))
   .withColumn("delta", F.abs(F.col("col")-F.col("int_col"))))

# groupby to find minimum delta rows for each id
df2 = (df1
   .groupBy("id")
   .agg(F.min("delta").alias("delta")))
       
# join df1 and df2 to retrieve rows with minimal "delta" from df1        
df_output = (df1
              .join(df2, ["id", "delta"])
              .select("id", "array_col", "int_col", F.col("pos").alias("closest_index")))
```